# Linker error in switching from cc compiler to g++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker

I have been using C to code for sometime and I had no issues in compiling and linking my code to archive libraries (.a files). However, now I need to switch to C++ and doing so, I have to use g++ instead of cc for linking and compiling.

Using C, first thing to do was compiling the source and creating the object file and then linking it to the library using the same command but without the -c option:

```
cc -c -ggdb -Wall -Werror -I.. test.c -o test.o
cc -o test -ggdb -Wall -Werror test.o ../libpmem/libpmem.a
```

As I think the same procedure should be done for doing the same thing with g++, I tried to change the compiling and linking phase as follow:

```
g++ -c -ggdb -Wall -Werror -I.. test.c -o test.o
g++ test.o -I.. -L/path/libpmem -lpmem -o test
```

Although both sets should do the same thing, I always get an error while trying to link using g++. Here is the error message:

```
test.o: In function `main':
/path/test/test.c:5: undefined reference to `pmem_msync_mode()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

There must be something wrong with the linking phase as the method definition must be found in the library file (just as the cc linker can find the definition and do the linking without any problem).

I also tried to do both linking and compiling using a single g++ command, but no matter what I do, I always get the same error. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: The choice of driver program (`gcc` or `g++`) should not matter, as the only difference between them is that `g++` automatically links with the C++ runtime library, while `gcc` does not. The actual compilation process checks the filename extension to know what kind of program it compiles, and so there *should* be no actual difference between using `gcc` or `g++` in this case, as it's still C code being compiled.

Comment: Oh by the way, when linking the preprocessor options (like `-I`) are not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably have some sort of name mangling problem...

since it looks like that is declared in a c library there should already be some sort of

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int pmem_msync_mode(); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but if there isn't in the library header you may have to do something like;

```
 extern "C" {
 #include <pmem.h>
}
```

Comment: For a single declaration you can also write simply: `extern "C" int pmem_msync_mode();`

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1143/

You need to tell the compiler that the code is compiled as C

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `pmem` library is compiled and linked as C code.

C and C++ have different conventions for how they store the names of functions in binary format.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling for a reference.

To solve your problem, probably the solution is to:

```
extern "C" {
#include <pmem.h>
}
```

When the C++ compiler imports the function declarations from the header, without external C linkage being specified, it expects the binary it links against to have the associated functions' representations in a different format, namely whatever format your C++ compiler mangles function names to.